# Package APPX in APPXBUNDLE

Tags: windows-store-apps, electron, electron-builder, desktop-bridge

I currently have one UWP app submitted in the Windows Store, now I want to publish an update. This update is based on Electron, so its not an UWP app anymore.

I just wanted to submit the Electron Application to the Windows Store, but I am getting this error message:`A previous submission for this app was released with a Windows 10 .msixbundle or .appxbundle. Subsequent submissions must continue to contain a Windows 10 .msixbundle or .appxbundle.`

The Electron app is packaged with `electron-builder` and the resulting file is an `appx` file. Previously I packaged the app with Visual Studio and the resulting file was an `appxbundle`.

According to this error message I must submit an `.msixbundle` or `.appxbundle` file. Can I just create an `.appxbundle` that contains the Electron `.appx` file and then submit the app to the Windows Store?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the promised answer to my own question.

As I already mentioned you must stick with the bundle format you initially submitted your App to the Microsoft App Store. So `.appxbundle` in my case.

I am using `electron-builder` which spits out an `.appx` which I then bundle into an `.appxbundle` using an `afterAllArtifactBuildHook`

Here is the `afterAllArtifactBuildHook.js` located in the `build/hooks` folder of my electron project. It automatically utilizes the already cached `winCodeSign` tools from `electron-builder` so it ensures everything matches.

**Note: This is geared towords macOS and a functional Parallels desktop installation with Windows 10 already setup to build `.appx` files**

```
var path = require("path"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    glob = require("glob"),
    childProcess = require('child_process');

exports.default = function(buildResult) {
    buildResult.artifactPaths.forEach(function(appxPath) {
        if (appxPath.endsWith(".appx")) {
            convertAppx2AppxBundle(appxPath);
        }
    });
};

/**
 * Converts a Unix Path to a Windows conforming path by replacing any "/" with "\"
 * @return {string}
 */
String.prototype.windowsify = function windowsify() {
    return this.replace(/\//g, "\\");
}

/**
 * Converts the given appx to an appxbundle used for Windows Store submission
 * @note This function utalizes the parallels desktop tool "prlctl" to execute windows commands via macOS
 * @param appxPath
 */
function convertAppx2AppxBundle(appxPath) {
    try {
        console.log("Converting Appx to Appxbundle...")
        // We'll use electron-builder's winCodeSign tools which are conveniently already available in the following dir
        var electronBuilderDir = path.join(process.env.HOME, "Library/Caches/electron-builder"), // Don't use "~" it will just not work, trust me...
            // Will use the first matching windowsCodeSigning path as we may have multiple versions installed
            makeAppX = glob.sync(path.join(electronBuilderDir, "winCodeSign", "winCodeSign-*", "windows-10", "x64", "makeappx.exe"))[0],
            appxBundleMapFile = // This file is required by the makeappx.exe to generate the appxbundle
                '[Files]\n' +
                '"\\\\Mac\\AllFiles' + appxPath.replace(/\//g, "\\") + '"\t\t"Loxone.appx"';

        // Save the generated AppxBundle.map file to the filesystem to make it available for the Windows VM
        fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "..", "AppxBundle.map"), appxBundleMapFile, { flag: "w" });

        var prlctlArgs = [
            'exec',
            '"Windows 10"', // the name of the specific Windows VM
            '--current-user', // We want to execute the following command with the current user
            // From this point on its the default Windows CLI command for converting an .appx to an .apppxbundle
            // Its important to know that these parts must conform to the Windows style, hence the windowsify function
            // We also need to use double quotation for the network shares due to how childProcess.execSync works...
            '"\\\\\\Mac\\AllFiles' + makeAppX.windowsify() + '"',
            'bundle',
            '/f',
            '"\\\\\\Mac\\AllFiles' + (__dirname.replace("/hooks", "") + "/AppxBundle.map").windowsify() + '"',
            '/p',
            '"\\\\\\Mac\\AllFiles' + appxPath.windowsify() + 'bundle"',
            '/o'
        ];
        // Now just execute the command to convert the appx to an appxbundle
        childProcess.execSync('prlctl ' + prlctlArgs.join(" "), { stdio: 'inherit' });
        console.log("Done converting Appx to Appxbundle");
    } catch (e) {
        console.warn("Couldn't convert appx two appxbundle!");
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, here is a step by step article from MSFT that shows how to generate a MSIX bundle for existing msix/appx packages.

- [building MSIX bundles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/bundle-msix-packages)

Comment: I am following the documentation, but there are some inconsistencies. It looks like the `/p` option is not supported and that I need a `Packaging Layout File`. Any advice?

Comment: Sorry, don't know all the details either. Maybe leave a comment on MSFT's article and they will get back to  you? Here is also a thread on package layout that might give you more details: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/MSIX-Packaging-and-Tools/Manually-creating-MSIX-packages-using-Packaging-Layout/m-p/356100#M337

Answer (score 1):

Steps that I used to updated an existing appbundle,

1. Build your APPX file(s)
2. Create a bundle.txt file

   [Files]
   ".\release_1.0.0.appx"           "release_1.0.0.appx"
3. If you installed VS2022, then open the x64_x86 Cross Tools Command Prompt
4. Change to the directory where your APPX files are located.
5. Execute the command,

   makeappx bundle /v /o /bv 1.0.0.0 /f bundle.txt /p release_1.0.0.appxbundle
6. You should then be able to upload on developer.windows.com dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

Electron Apps could be compiled for the Windows Store. Microsoft developed [a tool that compiles Electron apps as .appx packages](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-windows-store),enabling developers to use some of the goodies found in the new application model. The new .appx format does not only enable a number of new powerful APIs like Cortana or Push Notifications, **but through the Windows Store**, also simplifies installation and updating. You could refer to [Electron Documentation: Windows Store Guide](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/windows-store-guide#windows-store-guide) and [Microsoft Blog Compiling Electron Apps for the Windows Store](https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2016/05/08/compiling-electron-apps-for-the-windows-store/) for detailed steps and requirements.

Comment: I had a chat with an Microsoft Support employee, he pushed me into the right direction. I havn't had any issue with creating the `.appx` file, but with submitting it to the Windows Store. It looks like you need to stick to the bundled form if you previously submitted your application in the bundled form. This behaviour is somehow not documented well enough. I will answer my question later with a detailed guide.